# Doubly Linked list with Skip List to insert in sorted way

Tags: c++, list, sorting, linked-list, skip-lists

I read about skip list on internet and i just got idea about how its works with different data structures and all. But i really i want to implement skip list with doubly linked list as i want to sort doubly linked list at the time of insertion. Means when element insert at that time it should be insert in sorted way only.

Here i implement method to insert data in doubly linked list in sorted way but this takes a long time to insert data and make list in sorted way when number of elements are very large.

Please tell me how can i add skip list Algo in my existing function or i have to rewrite again whole thing? Any help with implementation would be appreciated

Here is code:

```
void DoubleList::addSorted(int value)
{
    IDoubleNode * tempNode = new DoubleNode();
    tempNode->setValue(value);
    // if double link list is empty 
    if(getHead() == NULL)
    {
        // temp node already has NULL value in next and prev.
        setHead(tempNode);
        setTail(tempNode);
    }
    else if(value <= getHead()->getValue())
    {
        tempNode->setNext(getHead());// set tempnode next as current head.
        tempNode->setPrev(getHead()->getPrev()); // set previous
        getHead()->setPrev(tempNode); // set previous pointer of head to tempnode which we just inserted
        setHead(tempNode); // set head
        getHead()->setPrev(NULL);// for safer side. we already done this.
    }
    else
    {
        int found = 0;
        IDoubleNode *currNode = getHead();
        while(currNode->getNext() != NULL && found == 0)
        {
            if(currNode->getNext()->getValue() > tempNode->getValue())
            {
                found = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                currNode = currNode->getNext();
            }
        }
        if(found)
        {
            tempNode->setNext(currNode->getNext());
            currNode->getNext()->setPrev(tempNode);
            currNode->setNext(tempNode);
            tempNode->setPrev(currNode);
        }
        else
        {
            currNode->setNext(tempNode);
            tempNode->setPrev(currNode);
            tempNode->setNext(NULL);
            setTail(tempNode);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The beauty of the skiplist is that it sorts the data items and also offers o(log n) insert and delete time complexity. To make it more understandable, imagine your linked list had short cuts or anchors such that you don't have to traverse the whole list to find the position to insert an item. You just follow the anchors, thus it is a double-linked list with quick access anchors.

As for implementation, if you don't intend to use the skip-list for multi-threaded access, then it becomes trivial to implement. There is no reason to combine a skip-list with a double-linked list, but you can implement a skiplist as a double-linked list

Look at
http://www.sanfoundry.com/cpp-program-implement-skip-list/

Comment: thanks for your reply. i guess there would be problem for set prev of each node in doubly linked list. hows that thing we can manage in Skip list

Comment: what is the motivation for having prev pointers in the skiplist?

Comment: I am implementing doubly linked list so it should have prev pointers because my unit test will check it reverse order also. It is correct or not.

Comment: You can look at this example implementation of skip-list with back pointers. http://www.coderslexicon.com/introduction-to-a-skiplist-data-structure-in-java/

Hope it can help, it does not add much complexity, but you will have to deal with a lot more pointers on every delete or insert of nodes.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps you.

```
#ifndef SkipList_h
#define SkipList_h
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

template<typename K, typename V, int MAXLEVEL>
class SkipListNode
{

public:
    SkipListNode()
    {
        for(int i=1; i<=MAXLEVEL;i++){
            next[i] = nullptr;
            prev[i] = nullptr;
        }
    }

    SkipListNode(K searchKey):key(searchKey)
    {
        for(int i=1; i<=MAXLEVEL;i++){
            next[i] = nullptr;
            prev[i] = nullptr;
        }
    }

    SkipListNode(K searchKey, V val):key(searchKey),value(val)
    {
        for(int i=1; i<=MAXLEVEL;i++){
            next[i] = nullptr;
            prev[i] = nullptr;
        }
    }

    // custom memory management
   // static void * operator new(size_t size);

  //  static void operator delete( void *deadObject, size_t size );


    K key;
    V value;
    SkipListNode<K, V, MAXLEVEL>* next[MAXLEVEL+1];
    SkipListNode<K, V, MAXLEVEL>* prev[MAXLEVEL+1];
private:
   // static MemoryPool<SkipListNode> memPool; // memory pool for SkipListNode
};

// template<typename K, typename V, int MAXLEVEL>
// MemoryPool< SkipListNode<K, V, MAXLEVEL> > SkipListNode<K, V, MAXLEVEL>::memPool;

// template<typename K, typename V, int MAXLEVEL>
// inline void * SkipListNode<K, V, MAXLEVEL>::operator new ( size_t size )
// {
//     return memPool.allocate();
// }

// template<typename K, typename V, int MAXLEVEL>
// inline void SkipListNode<K, V, MAXLEVEL>::operator delete( void *p, size_t size )
 //{
 //    memPool.deallocate( static_cast<SkipListNode<K, V, MAXLEVEL> *>(p) );
 //}


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

template<typename K, typename V, int MAXLEVEL = 16>
class SkipList
{
public:
    typedef K keyType;
    typedef V ValueType;
    typedef SkipListNode<K, V, MAXLEVEL> NodeType;
    const int maxLevel;

    SkipList(K min_key, K max_key)
                                :pHeader(nullptr), pTail(nullptr),
                                maxCurrLevel(1), maxLevel(MAXLEVEL),
                                minKey(min_key), maxKey(max_key)
    {
        pHeader = new NodeType(minKey);
        pTail = new NodeType(maxKey);

        for( int i = 1; i<=MAXLEVEL; i++){
            pHeader->next[i] = pTail;
            pTail->prev[i] = pHeader;
        }
    }

    virtual ~SkipList()
    {

        delete pHeader;
        delete pTail;
    }

    void removeAll()
    {
        NodeType* curNode = pHeader->next[1];
        while(curNode != pTail){
            NodeType* temp = curNode;
            curNode = curNode->next[1];
            delete temp;
        }
    }

    std::string printList()
    {
        std::stringstream sstr;
        NodeType* currNode = pHeader->next[1];
        while ( currNode != pTail ) {
            sstr << "(" << currNode->key << "," << currNode->value << ")" << std::endl;
            currNode = currNode->next[1];
        }
        return sstr.str();
    }

    NodeType* insert( K searchKey, V newValue );

    void removeKey( K searchKey );
    void removeKey( NodeType* curNode );

    NodeType* search(const K& key, NodeType** prev   );

private:
    K minKey;
    K maxKey;
    int maxCurrLevel;
    SkipListNode<K, V, MAXLEVEL>* pHeader;
    SkipListNode<K, V, MAXLEVEL>* pTail;

    double uniformRandom()
    {
        return rand() / double(RAND_MAX);
    }

    int randomLevel() {
        int level = 1;
        double p = 0.5;
        while ( uniformRandom() < p && level < MAXLEVEL ) {
            level++;
        }
        return level;
    }
};

template<typename K, typename V, int MAXLEVEL>
typename SkipList<K, V, MAXLEVEL>::NodeType* SkipList<K, V, MAXLEVEL>::search(const K& searchKey, NodeType** prev )
{
    NodeType* currNode = nullptr;

    currNode = pHeader;
    for (int level=maxCurrLevel; level>=1; level--) {
        // Start our search at previous level's predecessor

        while (currNode->next[level]->key < searchKey) {
            currNode = currNode->next[level];

        }
        if ( prev != nullptr) {
            prev[level] = currNode;
        }

        //currNode = currNode->next[level];
        /*
        if ( next != nullptr) {
            next[level] = currNode;
        }*/
    }

    currNode = currNode->next[1];
    return currNode;
}

template<typename K, typename V, int MAXLEVEL>
typename SkipList<K, V, MAXLEVEL>::NodeType*  SkipList<K, V, MAXLEVEL>::insert( K searchKey, V newValue )
{
    SkipListNode<K, V, MAXLEVEL>** next = nullptr;
    SkipListNode<K, V, MAXLEVEL>* prev[MAXLEVEL];

    auto foundNode = search(searchKey, prev);


    int newLevel = randomLevel();
    //std::cout<< "Level: "<<newLevel<< std::endl;

    if ( newLevel > maxCurrLevel ) {
        for ( int level = maxCurrLevel+1; level <= newLevel; level++ ) {
            prev[level] = pHeader;
        }

        maxCurrLevel = newLevel;
    }

    NodeType* curNode = new NodeType(searchKey, newValue);

    for ( int level = 1; level<=maxCurrLevel; level++ ) {
        curNode->next[level] = prev[level]->next[level];
        curNode->prev[level] = prev[level];
        prev[level]->next[level]->prev[level] = curNode;
        prev[level]->next[level] = curNode;
    }
    return curNode;
}

template<typename K, typename V, int MAXLEVEL>
void SkipList<K, V, MAXLEVEL>::removeKey( K searchKey)
{

    SkipListNode<K, V, MAXLEVEL>** prev1 = nullptr;

    auto curNode = search(searchKey, prev1);


    //std::cout<<curNode <<" -> "<< curNode->key<< std::endl;
    if ( curNode && curNode->key == searchKey ) {

        auto prev = curNode->prev;

        for ( int level = 1; level<=maxCurrLevel; level++ ) {

            if ( prev[level]->next[level] != curNode ) {
                break;
            }

            prev[level]->next[level] = curNode->next[level];
            curNode->next[level]->prev[level] = prev[level];
        }

        delete curNode;

        while ( maxCurrLevel > 1 && pHeader->next[maxCurrLevel] == pTail) {
            maxCurrLevel--;
        }

        //std::cout << "maxCurrLevel: "<<maxCurrLevel<<std::endl;
    }

}


template<typename K, typename V, int MAXLEVEL>
void SkipList<K, V, MAXLEVEL>::removeKey( typename SkipList<K, V, MAXLEVEL>::NodeType* curNode )
{
    if ( curNode && curNode == curNode->next[1]->prev[1] && curNode == curNode->prev[1]->next[1] ) {
       // std::cout<<curNode <<" -> "<< curNode->key<< std::endl;

        auto prev = curNode->prev;

        for ( int level = 1; level<=maxCurrLevel; level++ ) {

            if ( prev[level]->next[level] != curNode ) {
                break;
            }

            prev[level]->next[level] = curNode->next[level];
            curNode->next[level]->prev[level] = prev[level];
        }

        delete curNode;

        while ( maxCurrLevel > 1 && pHeader->next[maxCurrLevel] == pTail ) {
            maxCurrLevel--;
        }
    }
}


#endif
```